# JavaFX package which shows degree of closeness

Tags: javafx, package, javafx-8

I want to create a pictionary game in JavaFX. Now suppose player 1 draws a 'dog' (the user would have already input the name of the object that he/she is drawing)and the other player guesses it as 'fog' then the output should show that the 'word is close(nearly or really)'.

Is there an inbuilt package for this or is there a code?
As far as I know, there is a package in JavaScript but I don't know what it is called.

Comment: Do you mean string-similarity(the js package) - it is not built in. I think the LevenstheinDistrance class from apache commons text should do the trick(but it's not built-in too).

Comment: yes exactly thanks.

Comment: The other thing you could try is "Soundex" but I believe that would only work for English, which may be OK for you or not